# Acrobat Javascript Dates

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a text field that displays the date in mmmm d, yyyy (called 'Expiry Date') and I am trying to make three smaller fields that display just the day (d), the month (m), and the year (yyyy) in each field.

I have tried to import the data into each field using this code:

```
var sField = 'Expiry Date'
```

and then i would custom format it just to "d", "m", or "yyyy" as appropriate. In the little formatting preview window it would show the desired output, but the fields would still be blank.

What is also odd is that it will only work with formatting that starts with the month.

The field that Im getting the first date is created from another calculation if that makes it any different. 'Expiry Date' gets it's data from a field called 'date'. Here is the code in which it assigns an expiry date 30 days after the value of 'date'

```
// define the value for the date field
var sField = 'Date'
// define the format of the date string
var cFormatDate = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
// define some time constants
var fSecond = 1000; // number of milliseconds in one second
var fMinute = 60 * fSecond; // number of milliseconds in a minute
var fHour = 60 * fMinute; // number of milliseconds in an hour
var fDay = 24 * fHour; //number of milliseconds in a day
// get the field object's string value
var fTodayDate = this.getField(sField).value;
// convert the string value into a date object
var oDate = util.scand(cFormatDate, fTodayDate);
// convert the date object to a value in milliseconds
var fDate = oDate.getTime();
// add 30 days to value using the number of milliseconds in a day
var fNewDate = fDate + (30 * fDay);
// convert computed date value to date object
var oNewDate = new Date(fNewDate);
// set the field's value to the date string for the date object
event.value = util.printd(cFormatDate, oNewDate);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Acrobat, but assume its Date objects conform to ECMA-262. By far the best method of converting a date string to a date object is to parse it yourself, do not leave it up to the `Date` function/constructor or `Date.parse`.

From your post, it seems the date string is like `October 17, 2012`. There's a function below to help with that.

The best way to add whole days is to add them to the date, so given a date object:

```
// Create a new Date object
var now = new Date();

// Copy it
var then = new Date(now);

// Add 30 days
then.setDate(then.getDate() + 30);
```

Note that adding 30 to dates after 28 January (or 29 January in a leap year) will end up in March.

#### Edit

Date string parse function:

```
// Expects mmm d, yyyy e.g. October 17, 2012 or Oct 17, 2012
function parseDateString(s) {
    var months={jan:0, feb:1, mar:2, apr:3, may:4, jun:5, 
                jul:6, aug:7, sep:8, oct:9, nov:10, dec:11};
    var d = s.split(/\s/);
    return new Date(d[2], months[d[0].toLowerCase().substring(0,3)], parseInt(d[1],10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be over simplifying things, but if you have a date field (let's name it "DATE1") that has the full date in it.

Couldn't you just copy that field 3 time, assigning "DATE1" to the name for all three.  This would take the date that you typed into the original Date field and duplicate it throughout the other three.  Then just go into the field properties, ensure all 4 boxes are assigned the format "Date" -- and then on your 3 smaller boxes, assign them a Custom Date Option of "dd", "mm", or "yy" respectively?